# Fix horizontal scrolling in webpage

Tags: css, html, scroll

> I am currently working on a side project and i ran into something
>   annoying: When my browser size is smaller than around (1280 |
>   something) the content is not entirely viewable. I can scroll to the
>   right to see whats there, but not to the left.

**html:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
 [...]
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1200px;
 margin-right: -600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your centering technique is wrong.

use:

```
#wrapper {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

Also, using absolute positioning for layouts is generally a bad idea. Learn how to use floats, and get rid of the TABLEs too.

Comment: Or, to shorthand that a little use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's clearer now. While your answer does solve the scroll problem, it destroys the layout. I will follow a new approach for this project and follow your tip to look into floats!

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, margin-left: -600px is your problem. I agree with Diodeus. Absolute positioning and tables are generally frowned upon.